# Find the average salary several months back - MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, average

I want to find the average salary of the staffs who started work within 8 months ago.

I tried making the code but somehow it's displaying NULL..

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff  
WHERE salary = DATE_SUB(sWDate, INTERVAL 8 MONTH);
```

Everything is within this table.

Can anyone help me out please? I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Above SQL is valid, `Group By` is not required if you want to average salaries for employees here

Comment: Why are you comparing salary with a date? Which column is your joining date?

Comment: My mistake. I thought salary is equal to the date 8 months back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `salary = DATE_SUB(sWDate, INTERVAL 8 MONTH)`?

**WITHIN 8 MONTHS:**

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff  
WHERE sWDate <= NOW() AND sWDate >= DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH);
```

- [`Date_Sub`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Another:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff  
WHERE sWDate <= NOW() AND sWDate >= DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -8 MONTH);
```

- [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

PS: It's best that you format `Now()` according to the date format you have in `sWDate` to get precise results. Otherwise you can use `Year/Month`.

e.g.:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff  
WHERE Date_Format(sWDate,'%Y-%m') <= Date_Format(NOW(),'%Y-%m') 
AND Date_Format(sWDate,'%Y-%m') >= Date_Format(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -8 MONTH), '%Y-%m';
```

Comment: Thanks it works (first and second 1, haven't tried 3). 1 question how come ' SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff WHERE sWDate= DATE_SUB(sWDate, INTERVAL 8 MONTH); ' don't work?

Comment: My silly mistake! I forgot to put the minus sign before 8... thank you once again!

Comment: Please try and comment. Let us know if everything works fine for you. :)

Comment: It worked thank you bonCodigo =) I had to change salary to date and swap my date in date_sub with NOW() and also place a minus sign beside the month (8).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check `Date` field and not Salary for date

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff  
WHERE [DateField] = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH);
```