# SQL - How can I get the average employee salary for each department?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the UML for the tables:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html

[image]

This my attempt:

---

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(employees.first_name, ' ', employees.last_name) AS 'EmployeeName',
    salaries.emp_no AS 'Employee Number',
    departments.dept_no AS 'Department Number',
    departments.dept_name AS 'Department name',
    AVG(salaries.salary) AS 'Average salary'
FROM salaries
INNER JOIN dept_emp
    ON salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
INNER JOIN employees
    ON salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no
INNER JOIN departments
    ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
GROUP BY    salaries.emp_no,
            dept_emp.dept_no
```

---

I just get the average employee salary for all departments a person worked in.
My desired result must group by each employee for each department.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the current error or results you are getting?

Comment: the results are average for employee for all departments he worked in

Comment: Does an employee have multiple salaries in each department? If not, what does it mean to average the salaries in each department?

Comment: Why put employee name in there at all?

Comment: Salaries are not per-department. Why do you need an average for each employee for each department?

Comment: An employee only has one salary. What does it mean to average them?

Comment: each employee can work in more department i need to get average salary for each employee per each department he worked in

Comment: employee can get multiple salaries in each department

Comment: you need to add dept_no to salaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the average salary several months back - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654155/find-the-average-salary-several-months-back-mysql)

Comment: @Sherif no group by. dupe would be subject to scrutiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this query

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(employees.first_name, ' ', employees.last_name) AS 'EmployeeName',
    salaries.emp_no AS 'Employee Number',
    departments.dept_no AS 'Department Number',
    departments.dept_name AS 'Department name',
    Cte_DepartmentSalaries.AvgSalary AS 'Average Salary'

--AVG(salaries.salary) AS 'Average salary'

FROM salaries
INNER JOIN dept_emp
    ON salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
INNER JOIN employees
    ON salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no
INNER JOIN departments
    ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no   
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    departments.dept_no,
    departments.dept_name,
    AVG(Salaries.Salary) AS AvgSalary
FROM Salaries
INNER JOIN dept_emp
    ON salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
INNER JOIN departments
    ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
GROUP BY    departments.dept_no,
            departments.dept_name) AS Cte_DepartmentSalaries
    ON dept_emp.dept_no = Cte_DepartmentSalaries.dept_no
```

Comment: i couldn't execute that query i using mySQL not oracle

Comment: Updated query by not using common table expressions... can you check now?

Comment: The "average salary" returned by this query is for a given department, but includes *all* salary for *every* employee that ever worked in the given department, including salary when that employee worked in other departments. This must be the result OP is after (given that this is the selected answer). But it's very strange to name this result "average employee salary for each department", and to give the description as "get average salary for each employee per each department he worked in". This average is better described "all salary history of every employee that ever worked in a department"

Answer (score 1):

if you join to salaries where to_date between from and to date you will get any changes in the salary over those time periods.

```
SELECT  CONCAT(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) AS 'EmployeeName',
        s.emp_no AS 'Employee Number',
        d.dept_no AS 'Department Number',
        d.dept_name AS 'Department name',
        AVG(s.salaries.salary) AS 'Average salary'
FROM    employees e
        JOIN dept_emp de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
        JOIN salaries s ON s.emp_no = de.emp_no
                           AND (de.to_date >= s.from_date AND de.to_date <= s.to_date)
        JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept_no
GROUP BY s.emp_no,
        d.dept_no
```

Comment: I think the comparison of `s.to_date` should be to `de.from_date`, not `de.to_date`. This excludes any rows that have `to_date` as NULL, and also reports as the "average" the average of the  values of salary, without regard to the length of time at that salary. As a simple example, consider an employee works in a department for *three* years with a salary of 10,000, and then *one* year with a salary of 14,000. Would the average salary be 12,000? Or would it be 11,000?

Comment: @spencer7593  what if you just coalesce both to_date fields to current date

Answer (score 0):

Change your group by to

```
GROUP BY employees.first_name, employees.last_name,  
         salaries.emp_no, departments.dept_no, departments.dept_name
```

mysql lets you (in a non helpful way IMHO) not put all columns used in the group by.  Unlike other platforms that force you to put them all in if they are not in the aggregate function.  So you are getting more than one of the same row, but you can't tell because mysql squishes them for you.

---

you probably also need this in your join

```
INNER JOIN dept_emp ON salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
  AND salaries.from_date = dept_emp.from_date 
  AND salaries.to_date = dept_emp.to_date
```

Comment: problem is that the salary is duplicated for each department because there is no link from dept_no to salary.. grouping by more than just emp_no and dept_no won't solve anything in this case i believe

Comment: @JamieD77 - lets wait for the OP to try this and say it works.

Comment: @JamieD77 - I see what you mean -- he will have to include the dates in the join too I guess -- if that doesn't work then his model is FUBAR

Comment: give me the same problem

Comment: @abdelhamidahmed -- you have to join salery by date to department table -- how does you model work? as shown it is an impossible problem to solve

Comment: @abdelhamidahmed - see the edit about the join change.

Answer (score 0):

To find just the average salaries from a table use this mySQL query.

```
SELECT AVG(salary), COUNT(*) 
     FROM employees;MY
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However wehen answering please read the question carefully. The OP wanted average by department

Answer (score 0):

SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees
GROUP BY(departments_id);

Comment: This won't work unfortunately as salary is not a column in the employees table, At a minimum you would have to left join salaries, but with the assumption that salaries change over time, it's not as simple as a single join.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you would need to check for an overlap in the `from_date` and `to_date`, of the employee salary history (`salaries` table) and the employees department history (`dept_emp` table).

Assuming that a `to_date` value of NULL represents "current", to find the overlap, the join would be something like this:

```
 FROM salaries s 
 JOIN dept_emp de
   ON ( de.emp_no    = s.emp_no )
  AND ( de.from_date <= s.to_date   OR s.to_date  IS NULL )  
  AND ( de.to_date   >= s.from_date OR de.to_date IS NULL )
```

As far as getting the average salary, that's going to be a bit more complicated, depending on how you define "average".

As an example, if an employee worked in a department and the salary was 20,000 for *one* year, and then salary was 30,000 for *four* years... should the average salary be reported as  25,000 (the average of the two distinct values), or would it be 28,000 (total salary for all years, divided by the number of years.)

To get the latter result, we could use an expression that calculates the number of days the salary was effective for in the department...

```
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
       ,GREATEST(de.from_date,s.from_date)
       ,LEAST(IFNULL(de.to_date,DATE(NOW())),IFNULL(s.to_date,DATE(NOW())))
     )
```

We could multiple that by the effective salary, add all of those together, and then divide by the total number of days:

```
SUM(days*salary)/SUM(days)
```

An expression something like this:

```
SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
       ,GREATEST(de.from_date,s.from_date)
       ,LEAST(IFNULL(de.to_date,DATE(NOW())),IFNULL(s.to_date,DATE(NOW())))
     )
*
s.salary
)
/
SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
       ,GREATEST(de.from_date,s.from_date)
       ,LEAST(IFNULL(de.to_date,DATE(NOW())),IFNULL(s.to_date,DATE(NOW())))
     )
)
```